# GUI2exe py2exe not correctly importing module (python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe

I am trying to compile a program under windows 7 that my boss wants distrubuted as a single exe which means I cant use cx_freeze. however, the program has a library in it that is not getting picked up by py2exe called SVFS (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SVFS). I am using GUI2exe to try and simplify the process and i have looked for where the SVFS package is installed, It doesn't seem to be installed in the site-packages directory. When i run the python shell, the SVFS import works. So my question is:

How do I use python to find the exact location of every 3rd party module i have installed?
How do I then pass this information to py2exe and get my program up and running?

P.S for anyone who wonders why im not using pyinstaller, it is ancient and its not even running on my machines.

Comment: PyInstaller isn't ancient. It's actively maintained, but only supports Python 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to build the executable finally after trying VendorID, which was able to correctly pick up all dependicies and generate an exe with visual studio 2008 nmake.